# How to perform join query using Java stream

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I am fetching data from db and storing it in list. Then based on the the id, I want to create new Object. I have already implemented it using old for loop method. I am trying to implement it using java stream. Any help? Thanks.

```
        List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        emp.add(new Employee(1, "Ben", "Glasgow"));
        emp.add(new Employee(2, "Max", "Seattle"));
        emp.add(new Employee(3, "Sam", "Mumbai"));
        emp.add(new Employee(4, "John", "Aukland"));
        emp.add(new Employee(5, "Rob", "Tokyo"));

        List<Department> dpt = new ArrayList<Department>();
        dpt.add(new Department(1, 40000, "tech"));
        dpt.add(new Department(2,  30000, "mgm"));
        dpt.add(new Department(3,  50000, "tech"));
        dpt.add(new Department(4,  30000, "mgm"));


        List<EmpDep> empDep = new ArrayList<EmpDep>();
        
        /**How to do this using stream
        for (int i = 0; i < emp.size(); i++){
            empDep.add(new EmpDep(emp.get(i).getId(), emp.get(i).getName(), dpt.get(i).getSalary()));
        }
        */
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059548/how-to-traverse-multiple-list-using-java-8-stream

Comment: You said you want to join “based on the the id” but your loop is just combining objects at the same list index and will fail with an exception because the second list has not enough elements. There’s no sense to have as many departments as employees. The employee should have a property that determines the corresponding department and that property should not be the employee’s unique id. Then, consider doing the join in the database and fetch the result instead of doing the database’s job manually.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to create a [**stream**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from the `emp` list. Then transform the `Stream<Employee>` into `Stream<EmpDep>` using `map()` operation by creating an `EmpDep` object based on the `Employee` object precisely how you've done it the loop. And then collect all elements into a list using `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

```
        List<EmpDep> empDep = emp.stream() // Stream of Employee 
            .map(employee -> new EmpDep(employee.getId(), // Stream of EmpDep
                                        employee.getName(),
                                        employee.**getDeparment()**.getSalary()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note**, that in the code you've provided you are binding these two *lists* based on the *indices* of elements that makes your solution *brittle*. It'll be way better if the `Employee` class had a property that points to its *department*. Or `Department` class had a collection of *employee objects*. Or both options.

You must not connect reflect *relationships* between your *classes* *through data structures* like that, it's design fault.

To improve the class design I *encourage* you to add the **department property** and to the `Employee` class (getter to the property **getDeparment()** is used in the stream above).

Comment: employee(Employee class) does not have getSalary() method. getSalary() belongs to Department class

Comment: @RajB009 OK, I'll change the code in a moment.